Facing issues while re-initializing jquery DataTable
I am initializing the datatable on file input. I choose a csv file, parse it and initialize the datatable with the parsed data. It works fine for the first time, but I choose another file afterwards, the datatable is not being initialized properly. I have tried destroying the table in case it already exists but I am still getting errors while re-initializing it.
var csv_data;
    var file_name;
    $("#input_file").change(function() {

        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

            var file = this.files[0];
            file_name = file.name;
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {

                csv_data = e.target.result;

                // Parse CSV data to JavaScript objects
                var parsedData = parseCSVtoObjects(csv_data);
                console.log("Parsed Data : ", parsedData);

                // Check if parsed data is not empty
                if (parsedData.length > 0) {

                    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#dataTable")) {

                        $("#dataTable").DataTable().destroy();
                        $("#dataTable tbody").empty();

                    }

                    // Re-initialize DataTable with new data
                    initializeDataTable(parsedData);

                }

            };

            reader.readAsText(file); // Reading the file content as text

        }

    });

    function parseCSVtoObjects(csvData) {

        var lines = csvData.split("\n").filter(line => line.trim() !== "");
        if (
            lines.length < 2) return []; // Ensure there's at least one row of data

        var headers = ["Line Number"].concat(lines[0].split(","));
        var result = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

            var obj = {
                "Line Number": i
            };
            var currentLine = lines[i].split(",");

            if (currentLine.length !== headers.length - 1) {

                console.warn(`Skipping line ${i}: does not match the number of headers.`);
                continue;

            }

            headers.slice(1).forEach((header, index) => {

                obj[header.trim()] = currentLine[index].trim();

            });

            result.push(obj);

        }

        return result;

    }

    function initializeDataTable(data) {

        // Get headers from the first row of data
        headers = Object.keys(data[0]);

        // Build column definitions dynamically
        const columns = headers.map(header => ({
            "data": header,
            "title": header
        }));

        var first10Records = data;
        if (data.length > 10) {

            first10Records = data.slice(0, 11);

        }

        $("#dataTable").DataTable({
            "data": first10Records,
            "columns": columns,
            "paging": false, // Disables pagination
            "lengthChange": false, // Disables ability to change results number per page
            "searching": false, // Disables the search box
            "info": false, // Hides the table information
            "ordering": false,
            "bDestroy": true

        });
        $(".even").css("background-color", "#DCDBDB");
        $("th, td").css("width", "100px");

        var global_columns = [
            ["-1", "Not Used in Import"],
            ["date", "Date"],
            ["branch", "Branch"],
            ["start_time", "Start Time"],
            ["store_id", "Store ID"],
            ["end_time", "End Time"],
            ["rate", "Rate"],
            ["start_end_time", "Start End Time"],
            ["branch_with_store_id", "Branch With Store ID"]
        ];

        // Function to create a filter select element
        function createFilterSelect(id) {

            var select = $("<select></select>", {
                "id": id,
                "class": "rs_normal_text w2ui-select w2ui-field w2ui-input",
                "style": "width: 100%;"
            });

            global_columns.forEach(([value, text]) => {

                select.append($("<option></option>", {
                    "value": value,
                    "text": text
                }).clone());

            });

            return select;

        }
        filterPositions = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= headers.length - 1; i++) {

            filterPositions.push(i);

        }

        // Append filters to specified cells
        filterPositions.forEach((pos, index) => {

            $(`#dataTable tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq(${pos})`).html(createFilterSelect(`grid_filter_${index + 1}`));

        });

    }

    // Data table div start

    var $tableDivHeading = $("<div>Import Shifts </div>").attr("id", "tableDivHeading");
    $tableDivHeading.addClass("rs_listview_title").css({
        "width": "100%",
        "display": "flex",
        "align-items": "center",
        "justify-content": "center"
    });
    var $dataTableDiv = $("<div></div>").attr("id", "dataTableDiv");
    var $dataTable = $("<table></table>").attr("id", "dataTable").css({
        "height": "600px"
    });
    $("#container_grid").append($tableDivHeading);
    $("#container_grid").append($dataTableDiv);
    $("#dataTableDiv").append($dataTable);


Consider making this a functional snippet with HTML, a link to the library (and the version of that) and any CSS.  I also suggest removing all those blank lines as it just makes the scroll of the code longer and serves no real purpose;

Why is this not just in the CSS? $(".even").css("background-color", "#DCDBDB");         $("th, td").css("width", "100px");  You have a LOT of that type code that can make your code much simpler/smaller.

ALSO please post the text of the errors so we can be of the best help here.
